# How to resize image in jquery.filer

Tags: jquery, resize, image-uploading

I use [jquery.filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/) to upload image, works well but i don't find any option to resize the images, i.e., images in destination folder (uploadDir) has different size ( width or height) with original images in souce folder.
Please someone help me. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.iamrohit.in/crop-image-using-jquery-and-php/

Comment: try this code to crop image using jquery

Comment: @Ray please post your code

Comment: @Bilal  , but must refer to the jquery.filer
@ Massimo , we must download the package with many files, so can't post code, too much.